I want to deploy Node Js directly to IIS without going through the intermediate step (URL Rewrite)
Today I have a question about Deploy.
I want to upload Node JS to IIS. But when I researched, I only saw instructions on how to use IISNode, PM2,... to run the source under localhost and then Rewrite in the IIS configuration to put it on IIS.I don't want to run localhost but run directly from IIS. I want to ask if there is another way to build and run directly on IIS like .NET? Has anyone researched and tried this method?
Thank you everyone.
I have been using IISNode and URL Rewrite now I want to try another way.

If you spend more time on the research you might come across other options like, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Thanks LexLi, httpPlatformHandler acts as a bridge between IIS and the web application, forwarding HTTP requests from IIS to the web application and vice versa. But what I want is a way to build like ASP.NET directly to IIS. From a build folder push up and it works. I feel like running node on localhost is not too unstable.

ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core are treated specially as Microsoft has the resources to offer tight integration. So you have a group of dedicated developers to do the same?

I don't have such a development team. I was tasked with figuring out if there was a way to move the build directory from Strapi to IIS to get it to work. But while researching, all my searches required running node on localhost and using IIS as an intermediary. Is there no other solution?

To build tight integration with IIS for any language/framework, the work won't be less than what Microsoft did for ASP.NET Core in-process hosting mode, as the source code in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/v8.0.8/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2 revealed. Your research was not likely to hit that level, because no other as far as I know ever attempted. That's also why I am asking if you have the resources yourself to develop upon that. I think you have done enough to get back to your stakeholders.

Thank you for answering my question. It helps me a lot. Have a nice day.
